# How to add field classes from within template_preprocess_node

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, theming

During `template_preprocess_node` I would like to be able to dynamically add classes to specific field wrappers.

Is this possible or does `template_preprocess_node` run after `template_preprocess_field`? I would much prefer to use `template_preprocess_node` if possible as the class relies on other fields.

I've tried adding:

```
$vars['content']['field_name']['classes']
$vars['content']['field_name']['classes_array']
```

but neither seem to take effect.

Were I to do the same within `template_preprocess_field` then I apparently would add classes to `$classes_array` which would automatically flatten into `$classes`, however these values don't appear to be available, or at least provided, to `template_preprocess_node`?

EDIT:

After investigation, it seems `template_preprocess_node` does run first, however it doesn't seem to have access to `$classes_array` as it appears in `template_preprocess_field`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok my somewhat dirty solution was to pass a classes array from `template_preprocess_node` to `template_preprocess_field`:

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$vars){
  if(!isset($vars['content']['field_name']['classes_array'])){                                                                                   
    $vars['content']['field_name']['classes_array'] = array();                                                                                   
  }                                                                                                                                                          
  $vars['content']['field_name']['classes_array'][] = 'custom-class';
}

function template_preprocess_field(&$vars){                                                                                                                    
  if(isset($vars['element']['classes_array'])){                                                                                                                    
    $vars['classes_array'] = array_merge($vars['classes_array'], $vars['element']['classes_array']);                                                               
  }                                                                                                                                                                
}
```

If there's a more 'official' way to do this, please feel free to enlighten me and I'll re-award the answer :)